# questions on find and grep

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, find

With respect to the following `find` command-line

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l strings {} \;
```

I do not understand the usage of `-exec`  and `{}  \`.

Answer (score 6):

For each find (or directory) found, execute the following command:

```
grep -l strings {} \;
```

The {} is the place holder, which stands for the file/directory found. The \; is syntactically required.

Comment: the `\;` terminates the argument to `-exec` (it tells `find` to stop parsing the arguments as belonging to the command you want to run). You could pretty much use `";"` or `';'` instead - the point is, that without escaping the semicolon would be treated as command separator by the shell itself.

Comment: @peterph: Right on. Thank you for the explanation.